# Simple odds calculation

Tags: arithmetic

I'm stuck with a simple expression creation problem. I'd like to express odds by removing values from $100$ and arriving at a number. Every variable I use has value, that can either be $+10$ or $-10$, for instance. How do I factor this into an expression? If I do it like this:

$$R = 100 - (x_1 + x_2 + x_3)$$

I'll run into an issue if one of my variables $x_i$ is $+10$; it's supposed to add 10 instead of removing it (+ and - would give -), thus impacting my results. I assume this is something rather simple but my math knowledge is very insufficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please think more clearly about your question.  How does the number you arrive at "express odds"?  I can't understand what you are after at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, every variable can either improve or decrease odds by a certain percentage, so +10 would mean +10%. But buy editing my question, daOnlyBG answered it pretty much.